# podman-compose driver overlay not found on Mac M1

Tags: macos, apple-m1, podman, podman-compose

I'm getting an error running podman-compose after a fresh `brew install podman-compose` on my M1 MacBook :

```
podman-compose up   
podman-compose version: 1.0.6
['podman', '--version', '']
using podman version: 4.5.0
** excluding:  set()
['podman', 'ps', '--filter', 'label=io.podman.compose.project=docker_phx', '-a', '--format', '{{ index .Labels "io.podman.compose.config-hash"}}']
['podman', 'network', 'exists', 'docker_phx_webnet']
['podman', 'network', 'create', '--label', 'io.podman.compose.project=docker_phx', '--label', 'com.docker.compose.project=docker_phx', '--driver', 'overlay', 'docker_phx_webnet']
Error: failed to find driver or plugin "overlay"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/podman-compose/1.0.6/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/podman_compose.py", line 720, in assert_cnt_nets
    compose.podman.output([], "network", ["exists", net_name])
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/podman-compose/1.0.6/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/podman_compose.py", line 1098, in output
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd_ls)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['podman', 'network', 'exists', 'docker_phx_webnet']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/podman-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('podman-compose==1.0.6', 'console_scripts', 'podman-compose')())
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going on please ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my docker-compose.yaml :

```
version: "3.5"
networks:
  webnet:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true # Needed in order to run custom commands in the container

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    volumes:
      - "./volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - config/docker.env
    networks:
      - webnet
```

Taken from here : https://staknine.com/build-an-elixir-release-with-docker-to-deploy-anywhere/#add-docker-compose-file

Looks like the issue is coming from the driver configuration.
For some reason the driver is not reachable if installed.

Commenting the line resolve this error so good I guess.

Though another is error is displayed about "Operation not permitted" when `chown /var/lib/postgresql/data`

Is this specific to Mac environment ?